# If through row reduction of a square matrix you can produce a row of zeros does that automatically make that matrix singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

If through simple row operations such as adding one row to another I can produce a row of entirely zero does this mean that the matrix will be singular?

For example:

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 0 \\ 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 3\end{matrix} \right\}$$

Can be turned into the following by adding the first row to the fourth row

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 0 \\ 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\ 1 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 3\end{matrix} \right\}$$

Which can then be turned into the following by subtracting the second row from the first

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 0 \\ 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 \\ 1 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 3\end{matrix} \right\}$$

Now by subtracting the first row from the fourth 6 times we will produce a row of entirely $0$'s like so

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 3\end{matrix} \right\}$$

Since we have managed to produce a row of $0$'s does this mean that the rank of this matrix after further row operations is guaranteed to be less than 5 so according to the Invertible Matrix Theorem it should not be invertible/will be singular?

Is this logic sound or is their some other way we can determine that a large matrix is non invertible without doing intensive calculations?

Comment: Yes, the logic is correct. You may want to look up LU decomposition in Wikipedia and Crout's Algorithm. By that method, you can decompose your matrix into the product of a lower triangular and an upper triangular matrix. The product of the diagonal elements of the upper triangular matrix, if zero, implies the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: By the way, I do not feel computation is an important matter here. Once you know the algorithm, you can write a computer program that performs the necessary row reductions for you. In fact, that is the way Gaussian elimination, Gauss Jordan elimination, etc. work. You cannot row-reduce a 50 by 50 matrix!! So I would suggest that you use the algorithm to write a C program which will tell you whether your matrix is invertible or not by showing you the final form.

Comment: @yedaynara, solid lookup suggestions. The problem is not a matter of computational power. I have plenty of tools that will reduce the matrix or tell me if its singular. The problem I am faced with is determining singularity by hand. So while I agree that row reduction by hand is awful, it's what I am faced with.

Comment: Well, I am not quite sure that I can help you if you want to check singularity by hand. Anyway your procedure is correct. Another method would be, if you are so interested in working manually, to check for matrices $X$ such that $AX=0$, with $A$ being your matrix. If you can find two distinct matrices $X$ and $Y$ such that $AX=0$ and $AY=0$ then you can conclude that A is not invertible.

Comment: Assuming this is for a linear algebra course, typically row reducing anything 4x4 or smaller by hand is not so bad. If it is 5x5 or larger, there will almost always be a sequence of 3 or 4 moves which will either completely row reduce the matrix or produce a row of zeros (as you have done above).

Answer (score -3):

You're making this too complicated if your question is just about invertibility. Just compute the determinant. If either a row or a column of a matrix is entirely made of 0's, then the determinant will be 0 and by the equivalence theorem of linear algebra, the matrix is singular(noninvertible) . Of course, this will only work by hand if the matrix is relatively small-otherwise, you'll need a computer algebra program.

Interestingly, the same result is obtained if your algorithm produces 2 identical rows in a square matrix. Indeed, the result is equivalent to the previous one-just add the negative of one of the 2 rows to the other! You might think that this is just a computational quirk of square matrices, but it has far reaching consequences. To give just one-it's where the Pauli Exclusion principle of quantum mechanics comes from. When one expresses the wavefunction of fermionic particles via the Heisenberg matrix formulation, one can express it via the Slater determinant. If 2 fermionic particles-like electrons in the outer d and higher shells of an atom--occupy the same quantum states,then  2 rows or columns of the resulting matrix are identical. *But then when one applies the Slater determinant to compute the probability value of the square of a given wavefunction, the deteminant vanishes. This means the value of the probability of finding an electron in a given state is 0 and this means it's impossible!*

To find out more about this relationship, see any basic book on quantum mechanics or chemistry, like Ira Levine's very good book.

Comment: My fan club is at it again,I see.

Comment: I'm actually puzzled,not angry. I wish someone would explain to me what thier problem with this answer is-other then I wrote it,of course.